# how to count a words of a phrase and ignore the words with two characters in c++ using getche()

Tags: c++

i am new to c++ and i have a program in the university asked for counts the words with size greater than two characters and the number of all characters (ignore spaces) in a phrase typed in by the user. The program accepts the phrase character by character using the function getche() in the header  file  until press the enter key. Interaction with the program might look like this:

Enter the text: welcome to c++
         Count of words is: 2
         Count of characters is: 
i stopped at this steps and find a problem in ignoring words with two characters,please help...

```
#include <iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){

int chcount=0;
int wdcount=1;
int spccount=0;
char ch;
cout<<"Please,Enter a phrase :"<<endl;


while((ch=getche())!='\r'){
if(ch!=' '){
    chcount++;

}else if (ch==' '){
    wdcount++;


}



}
cout<<"Count of words is : "<<wdcount<<endl;
cout<<"Count of Letters is : "<<chcount<<endl;
//cout<<"Count of space :"<<spccount<<endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: So what's your question? The program is a pretty good start.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can figure out a way to keep track of how many non-space characters you've read since the last space you read.

Comment: @Gad the correct answer is here:(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26998115/c-phrase-counter-with-getche-function/26999369#26999369) as your friend asked there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#include<conio.h>

int main()
{

int chcount = 0, wdcount =0, count = 0;
char ch='a';

cout << "Enter your text : ";
while ( ch != '\r' )
{
  ch = getche();
  if ( ch !=' ' )
  {
       chcount++;
       count++;          
  }
  else if (count > 2)
       {
                wdcount++;
                count=0;
       }
}


cout<<"\nCount of words is: "<<wdcount+1<<"\nCount of charcters is: "<<chcount-1<<"\n";

system("pause");
return 0;}
```

By the way I'm your colleague Karim Fouad :) hope this helps

Comment: at issr ? Karim Fouad