# C++ phrase counter with getche() function

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#include<conio.h>

int main()
{

int chcount = 0, wdcount =0, count = 0;
char ch='a';

cout << "Enter your text : ";
while ( ch != '\r' )
 {
      ch = getche();
      if ( ch !=' ' )
      {
           chcount++;
           count++;          
      }
      else if (count > 2)
           {
                    wdcount++;
                    count=0;
           }
  }


  cout<<"\nCount of words is: "<<wdcount+1<<"\nCount of charcters is: "<<chcount-1<<"\n";

system("pause");
return 0;}
```

this code counts the words with size greater than two characters and the number of all characters (ignore spaces) in a phrase typed in by the user.
The question is why the word counter initial value is considered +1 and character counter initial value considered -1 (as you can see the cout wdcount+1 and chcount-1)?

Comment: The code doesn't even compile - what's `coun` for example ? Please post the *actual* code, and also please try to format it properly.

Comment: `chcount-1` because `\r` gets counted when it shouldn't, and `wdcount+1` because the last word isn't counted

Comment: Probably, in the line `else if (coun > 2)` you meant to use the variable `count`, right?

Comment: yes sorry i meant count but forgot t :) now it's correct I think

Comment: @DrewMcGowen how `\r` could be counted while `ch != '\r'` is the condition of `while`

Comment: @KarimFouad Are you sure the code is correct? From where did you get the code?

Comment: @PaulR (I don't think it will make difference to the concept of the question :D) now it's correct so what is the answer :)

Comment: @DrewMcGowen how \r gets counted? as if you pressed Enter code wouldn't get through While loop and wordd counter wouldn't be incremented .. same for character counter

Comment: @HanaBizhani try it out it will works fine .. as you wanna be sure you can check Robert Lafore Object-Oriented Programming C++ page 100 you will find similar code but counts all words and all characters (but have a small problem it counts words if you enter "Space" so if you enter 10 spaces for example after one word it will count 10 words!)

Comment: @KarimFouad I meant the logic of the code has problem not the syntax. So you changed the code. Would you please provide us the main source code ?

Comment: @HanaBizhani a book called "Object-Oriented Programming in C++ Fourth edition by Robert Lafore" Page 100

Comment: @HanaBizhani `\r` is counted because the condition `ch != ' '` is checked *before* the `ch != '\r'` condition. If `getche` returns `\r`, the `if` statement executes, *then* the `while` condition fails and exits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tries I finally got the correct answer I liked to post it to help anyone interested .. thanks all for your help

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#include<conio.h>

int main()
{


int chcount = 0, wdcount =0, count = 0;
char ch=' ';

cout << "Enter your text : ";

while ( ch != '\r' )
 {

      if ( ch !=' ' )
      {
           chcount++;
           count++;      
      }
      else if (count > 2)
           {
                    wdcount++;
                    count=0;             
           }
   ch = getche();
  }

  if (count >2)  //validate that last word is counted
  wdcount++;

  cout<<"\nCount of words is: "<<wdcount<<"\nCount of charcters is: "<<chcount<<"\n";

 system("pause");
 return 0;

}
```

Comment: It's exactly what I told you in the response. As you didn't accept my answer it made me -15 lost :)